# Ruby on Rails - How to set cron on local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

Suppose, we have a rake task, to be run like,

`rake RAILS_ENV=development parse_and_insert_feed_in_db`

We can set this task to be execute repeatedly on server using crontab's.

`1 0 * * *  rake RAILS_ENV=development parse_and_insert_feed_in_db > /some/dir/file.log`

How can we set a rake task to be executed on local machine like we set cron on server?

Comment: What is the OS of the local machine?

Comment: Suppose, we have to set it on MAC OS X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try like this:

```
1 0 * * *  /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/your/Application/path && rake RAILS_ENV=development parse_and_insert_feed_in_db > /some/dir/file.log'
```